# Css modules, extract properties to write inline style

Tags: javascript, css-modules

I need to generate HTML that will be used in two scenarios - 
a preview of what an email will look like when sent off, 
an email that will work in multiple clients.

HTML email has many peculiarities and ways that various clients might render it, therefore I would prefer to put out elements with style attributes instead of classNames, however I will still need to do an external css for some things that will be attempting to deal with client peculiarities.

So assuming I have something like the following

```
import * as React from "react";
import styles from './Email.module.css';

class EmailHeader extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (<table className="emailHeader">

...
```

I would prefer be able to do something like this

```
import * as React from "react";
import './vendorSpecificEmailStyles.css';
import styles from './Email.module.css';

class EmailHeader extends React.Component{
    const headerRule = styles.emailHeader.getRule();
    render(){
        return (<table className="emailHeader" styles={headerRule}>

...
```

I don't think this is possible with current CSS modules, but maybe somebody knows a library that already does it.

Comment: A simple solution to this is use inline styling.

Comment: @ravibagul91 yes but that's not what I to do. I want to maintain the css somewhere and inline styles is a lousy place to maintain css. Furthermore I obviously want to use css modules, including all the functionality available to get the correct style to process.

Answer (score 1):

Ok basically the answer to this is to use Juice. https://github.com/Automattic/juice

If you have all of your stylesheets inline on the page you can just do

```
Juice(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

if some of the stylesheets are external to the page you will need to loop through all css rules and get the cssText, concatenate them together like so

```
let allStyles = "";
for (let r = 0; r < document.styleSheets.length; r++ ){
    const css = document.styleSheets[r];
    const rules = css.cssRules ? css.cssRules : css.rules;
    for ( let i = 0; i < rules.length; i++ ){
        const rule = rules[i]
        allStyles = allStyles + rule.cssText;
    }
}
Juice.inlineContent(document.documentElement.innerHTML, allStyles);
```

I'm not sure if the above will work in IE11, but for most browsers you encounter it will be fine.

Comment: perhaps there should be a way to say - the way the question envisioned solving the problem is not doable, this answer suggests a workaround, that workaround has other tags than the question.